# Java - Utility method to pass a url and get its InputStream

Tags: java, url, inputstream

I wanted to write a Utility function something like this

```
public static InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {...}
```

so that I can use that `InputStream` according to my usage.

**e.g.**

If want to download a song, then I can directly write bytes from the InputStream to a file without converting bytes ->> String -->> file

OR

If I want to read some text from the url, then I can convert the InputStream to String.

**Problem:**

1. When I am using this InputStream in my caller function, I am getting the following exception

   ```
   java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:204)
   at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:182)
   at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:138)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
   at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2001)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803)    
   at hungama.HungamaContentDownloader.downloadContent(HungamaContentDownloader.java:87)
   at hungama.HungamaContentDownloader.main(HungamaContentDownloader.java:46)
   ```
2. Let's say even If I am able successfully read the content from the InputStream, How can I close the `HttpConnection` that I created inside this utility function? If I close it before returning, then the InputStream won't work. And If I don't close it before returning from the utility function, then the connection will remain unclosed.

Note: I don't want to return `byte []` or `String` from the utility function because in some cases the data might be very large because of which I can't store the whole data in memory before operating on that data.

**Code:**

```
public static InputStream getRemoteHttpResource(String url, String username, String password, int timeout) {
    if(url == null)
        return null;

    DefaultHttpClient client = null;
    HttpGet request = null;
    try {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, timeout);

        request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200)
            return response.getEntity().getContent();
        else
            logger.warn("Error response : " + statusLine + ". For : " + url + ". Response: " + response);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if(request != null)
            request.releaseConnection();
        if (client != null)
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Note: I am using `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`

Comment: Copy the IS to a `byte[]`.

Comment: You might be getting a socket closed exception because your not sending the correct headers. Alot of servers will boot you if they dont get things like user agent. Send a request using your browser, copy the headers and set the ones that look appropriate.

Comment: @ns47731 If I convert the same InputStream to a String or byte[] inside the utility function itself, then it is working.. so I am sure that I am sending the correct HttpRequest

Comment: @LutzHorn I don't want to convert the IS to a `byte[]` because in many cases the data might be too long to store in the memory before saving it to a file. So I want to use the IS so that I can stream the data directly to a file

Comment: @YatendraGoel my apologies I failed to understand your problem. It is closing because your finally statement is firing when you return the inputstream. You should probably either convert your method to a pipe stream method where you write the input to output or return the client or request in some fashion so they can be closed outside the method. It would be up to you as its a design pattern that would need to fit with your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do:

```
void pipRemoteHttpResource(String url, String username, String password, int timeout, OutputStream out) {
    .. same code ..
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200)
        pipeStreams(response.getEntity().getContent(), out);
    .. same code ..
}


// writes input to output
public static void pipeStreams(java.io.InputStream source, java.io.OutputStream destination) throws IOException {

    // 16kb buffer
    byte [] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int read = 0;
    while((read=source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        destination.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    destination.flush();
    destination.close();
    source.close();
}
```

Comment: +1 Instead of `pipeStreams(...)` method, we can use `IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out)`

Answer (score 3):

You could return your own implementation of `InputStream` that wraps the InputStream of the connection and override the `close` method. A `FilterInputStream` would already do most of the job, as it delegates the operations to the enclosed `InputStream`.

Comment: +1 This will work but I guess passing `OutputStream` to the utility method instead of returning `InputStream` from it would be better.